# Laravel Eloquent Complex Join Statement - specific example provided

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have the following raw SQL that I'm trying to convert into Eloquent form:

```
    SELECT oe.eventID, oe.eventName, oet.etName, date_format(oe.eventStartDate, '%c/%d/%Y') as eventStartDate, 
           date_format(oe.eventEndDate, '%c/%d/%Y') AS eventEndDate
    FROM `org-event` oe
    JOIN `org-event_types` oet on oe.eventTypeID=oet.etID and oet.orgID=?
    JOIN `event-registration` er on er.eventID = oe.eventID 
    WHERE (er.regStatus='Active' or er.regStatus='In Progress') AND personID=? AND oe.deleted_at is NULL
    ORDER BY oe.eventStartDate DESC
```

I've crafted the following and I'm running into an error saying that '10' isn't a column.  10 is the value of $this->currentPerson->defaultOrgID

```
    DB::table('org-event')
            ->join('org-event_types', function($join) {
                $join->on('org-event_types.etID', '=', 'org-event.eventTypeID');
                $join->on('org-event_types.orgID', '=', $this->currentPerson->defaultOrgID);
            })->join('event-registration', 'event-registration.eventID', '=', 'org-event.eventID')
            ->where('event-registration.personID', '=', auth()->user()->id)
            ->where(function($w) {
                $w->where('event-registration.regStatus', '=', 'Active')
                  ->orWhere('event-registration.regStatus', '=', 'In Progress');
            })
            ->select('org-event.eventID', 'eventName', 'etName', 'eventStartDate', 'eventEndDate')
            ->orderBy('org-event.eventStartDate')->get();
```

I dropped the deleted_at where clause because that's automatic using eloquent.

Comment: $join->on('org-event_types.orgID', '=', $this->currentPerson->defaultOrgID); here you have to mention column name instead of $this->currentPerson->defaultOrgID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join on the corresponding foreign key: `oe.eventTypeID=oet.etID` and then supply a `where` explaining what you want to filter your results by, i.e. `->where('orgID','=',$this->currentPerson->defaultOrgID)`.

```
DB::table('org-event')
            ->join('org-event_types', function($join) {
                $join->on('org-event_types.etID', '=', 'org-event.eventTypeID');
                $join->on('org-event_types.orgID', '=', 'org-event.eventTypeID')->where('orgID','=',$this->currentPerson->defaultOrgID);
            })->join('event-registration', 'event-registration.eventID', '=', 'org-event.eventID')
            ->where('event-registration.personID', '=', auth()->user()->id)
            ->where(function($w) {
                $w->where('event-registration.regStatus', '=', 'Active')
                  ->orWhere('event-registration.regStatus', '=', 'In Progress');
            })
            ->select('org-event.eventID', 'eventName', 'etName', 'eventStartDate', 'eventEndDate')
            ->orderBy('org-event.eventStartDate')->get();
```

Comment: This worked for me after changing an "ambiguous orgID" error message which was easy enough to address.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it!